# Failure when applying custom external gradle plugin to multi-module gradle project

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm having a hard time applying my custom external gradle plugins to an existing multi-module project. My project's structure looks like this:

```
my-app/
├─ buildSrc/
│  ├─ build.gradle.kts
├─ module1/
│  ├─ build.gradle.kts
├─ module2/
│  ├─ build.gradle.kts
├─ settings.gradle.kts
```

I've now implemented a couple of custom **binary plugins** which live in another repository and publishing them to `mavenLocal()` like so:

**Plugin Repo Code**

```
gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("plugin") {
            id = "organization.gradle.my-conventions"
            implementationClass = "organization.gradle.MyConventionsPlugin"
            version = "0.0.1"
        }
        create("plugin2") {
            id = "organization.gradle.my-other-conventions"
            implementationClass = "organization.gradle.MyOtherConventionsPlugin"
            version = "0.0.1"
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Project Code**

In my main project, I've configured `settings.gradle.kts` to resolve plugins from `mavenLocal` and apply one of the plugins (let's say **plugin1**) in the `build.gradle.kts` of **module1**. This looks like this:

```
plugins {
  id("organzation.gradle.MyConventionsPlugin") version "0.0.1"
}
```

This doesn't work though. I end up getting a stacktrace saying:

```
> Failed to apply plugin class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.scripting.internal.ScriptingGradleSubplugin'.
   > Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Action) when the project is already evaluated.
```

I tried the same way of applying the plugins in a non multi-module project (i.e. a single `build.gradle.kts`) and the plugins are applied as expected. So this most likely has to do with the multi-module aspect of it and some additional config?

Comment: It looks like you've made a mistake in the plugin. It's not easy writing a Gradle plugin, so it's understandable! Without looking at the code it's impossible to find out what's wrong, can you update your question to include it? Specifically regarding any code that applies `afterEvaluate { }`. I guess it's doing something like `rootProject.afterEvaluate { }` - but this won't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle 7 Migration: Failed to apply PublishPlugin (maven-publish): Cannot run afterEvaluate when the project is already evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68586807/gradle-7-migration-failed-to-apply-publishplugin-maven-publish-cannot-run-af)